# Getting number of page likes, post shares and website clicks

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

How can I get number of page likes, post shares and website clicks aggregated by ad group. Post comments and post likes are fetched through field 'inline_actions' - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adreportstats#columns (/reportstats/date_preset=yesterday&data_columns=['adgroup_id','inline_actions']&actions_group_by=['action_type']). I need a way to fetch these report items using api, just like they are returned using https://www.facebook.com/ads/manage/reporting.php.

Comment: the easiest way to do this is to configure the report you want via the reporting interface, schedule it and then read the configuration back via the API using: /act_<id>/adreportschedules

Answer (score 1):

To get data per adgroup level you must include `adgroup_id` or `adgroup_name` in `data_columns` - as you're doing.

Comments, Likes and many other actions are returned in column `actions`

You can specify which actions types you're interested in by specifying filters:

```
 filters=[
 {
    "field": "action_type",
    "type": "in",
    "value": [
        "like",
        "page_engagement",
        "post_engagement",
        "post_like",
        "comment",
        "games.plays",
        "post",
        "photo_view",
        "link_click",
        "receive_offer",
        "checkin",
        "mention",
        "tab_view",
        "vote",
        "follow",
        "gift_sale",
        "video_play",
        "video_view",
        "offsite_conversion",
        "offsite_conversion.checkout",
        "offsite_conversion.registration",
        "offsite_conversion.lead",
        "offsite_conversion.key_page_view",
        "offsite_conversion.add_to_cart",
        "offsite_conversion.other",
        "app_install",
        "app_engagement",
        "app_story",
        "app_use",
        "credit_spent",
        "mobile_app_install",
        "app_custom_event",
        "app_custom_event.fb_mobile_activate_app",
        "app_custom_event.fb_mobile_complete_registration",
        "app_custom_event.fb_mobile_content_view",
        "app_custom_event.fb_mobile_search",
        "app_custom_event.fb_mobile_rate",
        "app_custom_event.fb_mobile_tutorial_completion",
        "app_custom_event.fb_mobile_add_to_cart",
        "app_custom_event.fb_mobile_add_to_wishlist",
        "app_custom_event.fb_mobile_initiated_checkout",
        "app_custom_event.fb_mobile_add_payment_info",
        "app_custom_event.fb_mobile_purchase",
        "app_custom_event.fb_mobile_level_achieved",
        "app_custom_event.fb_mobile_achievement_unlocked",
        "app_custom_event.fb_mobile_spent_credits",
        "app_custom_event.other",
        "rsvp"
    ]
 }
 ]
```

However that's optional IIRC, API should send you all non-zero actions by default.